# Table construction problem while creating database for a lot of users

Tags: mysql, database-design

well, I have a problem with the concept of a database structure for pages to hold information about videos posted on the page and the user to be able to save as watched, make lists, and so on. The problem arises when I want to create a table that will just hold this information, which episodes the user watched. Suppose there are hundreds of thousands of these episodes. I thought about putting it in one row.I don't mean a ready-made solution, an idea or a little help.

Answer (score 1):

As a very basic example, you would need a table for users and a table for episodes. From there you could create and a table for, say, watched videos that contains relationships to the user and episode tables. Within that (watched) table you could have information about the viewing information for that particular user and video.

Outside the scope of the question, it sounds like you are new to database design and you might want to find a course or book that goes over the basics so you can avoid painful pitfalls as your project progresses.